# Enviromental issue for ORA-00911: ORA-00911: invalid character\n not due to missing semi-colon ;

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, iis, ora-00911

I have a website connected to an Oracle database. When I execute the following SQL I get a result returned:

```
select distinct name from CONTACTS
            where upper(EMAIL) like upper(:info) 
            AND HASACCESS（NAME, :userid) = 'Y' 
            order by NAME desc
```

I have migrated the same code to a new server. When this code runs I now get the error:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character\n
```

I do not have a `;` on the end which most people get when they get this error.

Doing some trial and error it is crapping on the call to the Stored Producer / Function call. The database that both bits of code are referencing are the same.

It is not to do with the bind variables because if I hard code them then I still get the error.

I am really perplexed on this one.

Comment: Please show us your effective C# code containing and executing the SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. It can be seen here

```
select distinct name from CONTACTS
            where upper(EMAIL) like upper(:info) 
            AND HASACCESS（NAME, :userid) = 'Y' 
            order by NAME desc
```

When the function is being called it is using the wrong bracket. It is using `（` it should be `(`.

PLSQL can run either bracket fine.

Changing the bracket the code now works.

Must be a difference in Oracle driver support. Or something else environmental. Hopefully this may help someone else one day...